# "audit" doesn't get included in Yocto final image

Tags: yocto, audit, selinux

I have included `meta-selinux` layer in my project source code. As `audit` is already present in `meta-selinux/recipes-security/audit`, have added this audit recipe to my yocto image by `IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " audit"` in machine specific conf file, but when I compile  image(`core-image-sato`) and flash it on device, I do not see any user space audit process running. I need `audit` to figure out SELinux violations and other debugging purpose.

> Why 'audit' is not getting installed in yocto image(core-iamge-sato)?

I know I can see SELinux violations messages in **/var/log/messages** but I want to have user space `audit` running on my device so that I can debug better

Thanks for time !!

Comment: Does your kernel support audit?

Comment: How do I know that?

Comment: I'm not audit user yet so I'm not sure about all of this. Which virtual/kernel provider do you use? Is it `linux-yocto` as it is enabled by those [bbappend files](http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/meta-selinux/tree/recipes-kernel/linux). If I remember correctly, linux-audit patches are integrated from `4.18 kernel version`.

Comment: `uname -r` gives me `4.14.35-intel-pk-standard`

Answer (score 0):

Can you check `meta-selinux` is included in `bblayers.conf`. Check your `build-***/conf/bblayers.conf`. Then include the `audit` package in `build-***/conf/local.conf`.

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " audit"
```

Then build `audit` package and check its built successfully. Then build the core-image-sato and flash the image.

Comment: As I explained, I already tried out what you are suggesting, nothing works out

Answer (score 0):

You need to include auditd

```
like: IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " audit auditd"
```